# MySQL Error #1142 with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `PP`
INNER JOIN `CM_MASTER`.`LOCATIONGUID` 
ON `PP`.`ADDR` = `CM_MASTER`.`ADDRESS1` 
AND `PP`.`ZIP` = LEFT(`CM_MASTER`.`POSTALCODE`,5);
```

I am trying to return all columns in the PP table with the matching LOCATIONGUID record from the CM_MASTER table when the street address and zip matches between the 2 tables. The above code returns the error:

```
 #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'ameridw5'@'localhost' for table 'LOCATIONGUID'
```

I am running this query in phpMyAdmin.
Can someone point me in a direction that will work?

**EDIT:**
cm_master table has address1, zip and LOCATIONGUID columns.
pp table has addr and zip columns.
if pp.addr = cm_master.address1 and pp.zp = cm_master.zip then
return the record in the query with cm_master.LOCATIONGUID joined to it.
is this possible?

Comment: change `CM_MASTER.LEFT(POSTALCODE,5)` to this `LEFT(CM_MASTER.POSTALCODE,5)`

Comment: Make that an answer so we can upvote you, please.

Comment: Does the user you are querying as have permission to select from the `LOCATIONGUID` table?  Try selecting directly from it.

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to place the `LEFT` around the `table_name.column_name` instead of splitting the table_name and column_name.

So change

```
CM_MASTER.LEFT(POSTALCODE,5)
```

to this

```
LEFT(CM_MASTER.POSTALCODE,5)
```

The full query will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PP`
INNER JOIN `CM_MASTER`
  ON `PP`.`ADDR` = `CM_MASTER`.`ADDRESS1` 
  AND `PP`.`ZIP` = LEFT(`CM_MASTER`.`POSTALCODE`,5) ;
```

<strike>Edit, It is not clear what your table structure is but is you need the `LocationGUID`, then possibly you need to add that column as well:</strike>

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PP`
INNER JOIN `CM_MASTER`
  ON `PP`.`LOCATIONGUID` = `CM_MASTER`.`LOCATIONGUID` 
  AND `PP`.`ADDR` = `CM_MASTER`.`ADDRESS1` 
  AND `PP`.`ZIP` = LEFT(`CM_MASTER`.`POSTALCODE`,5) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, i just did that and it still throws the same error.

Comment: @user2344300 See my edit, Is `cm_master` the table name?  If so, then you don't need to have `LOCATIONGUID` on the end of it. Or is the table named `LOCATIONGUID`?

Comment: yes, cm_master is the table name and taking LOCATIONGUID off the end of it does make it work, but it ends up joining the 2 tables complete instead of just the LOCATIONGUID column of the cm_master table to the entire PP table.

Comment: @user2344300 Does the `PP` table have `LocationGUID`?  You might need to edit your OP with the table structures and then what you are trying to do.

Comment: original post edited with what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user2344300 If you are joining the table on both `address` and `zip`, then you will be returning the `LocationGUID` associated with it.

Comment: No query changes are going to fix the fact that he's getting a *permissions error*. Regardless of the query, he doesn't have rights to execute it.

Comment: @Adrian The issue is that they are attempting to join on a table_name.column_name. It is NOT a permission issue. `CM_MASTER.LOCATIONGUID` is the table with column, there is not a table named `LocationGuid`. If you join `INNER JOIN CM_MASTER.LOCATIONGUID` it assumes db.table, that is not the case for this query.  If you read the entire question and comments you would see that, as a result I don't think this deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

seems that this user `ameridw5` didnt have permission on the table `LOCATIONGUID`

just set permission to this user all privilege

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on mydb.* to 'ameridw5'@'localhost' identified by 'you';
```

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html